# Getting local data up to Azure

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I could use some help getting my app's data up to Azure.

My app works fine locally (ie all the CRUD functions work on the views for my 3 tables), and when I publish to Azure the current code is pushed up and is available on the azurewebsites.net site.

The add-migration and update-database commands are keeping my local data structured and seeded properly as I muck around with the data model. All that is good.

My problem is that I don't know how to push the current state of the database up to azure along with the current state of the code.  Can someone toss me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain from your description, but [this](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) tool might help.